# In a DataTable object, how can I get a list of columns and their min/max string.Length?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm getting a string truncation error when I attempt `SqlBulkCopy` and I need to debug which field is causing it.

I have this so far.  I can get the column names but don't know how to proceed to get their min/max string.length.

```
var columnNames = from columns in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                  select columns.ColumnName;
```

I don't know if it's possible with LINQ.  If it isn't, I'm open to dumping this into SQL server and perform the analysis there too.

Comment: Are you looking for the defined maximum length of the column, which might not be set, or the length of the longest string stored in the column?

Comment: @RichardDeeming The latter:  The longest string **stored** in the column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the length of the longest string stored in the column, something like this should work:

```
var columns = 
    from DataColumn column in table.Columns
    where column.DataType == typeof(string)
    select new
    {
        column.ColumnName,
        MaxLength = 
        (
            from DataRow row in table.Rows 
            where !row.IsNull(column) 
            select ((string)row[column]).Length
        ).Max()
    };
```

Or, in lambda syntax:

```
var columns = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(column => column.DataType == typeof(string))
    .Select(column => new 
    { 
        column.ColumnName, 
        MaxLength = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
            .Where(row => !row.IsNull(column))
            .Select(row => ((string)row[column]).Length)
            .Max() 
    });
```

---

**EDIT:** You could also start with the rows and enumerate the columns for each row, which *might* give you better performance over a large table:

```
var columns =
    from DataRow row in table.Rows
    from DataColumn column in table.Columns
    where column.DataType == typeof(string) && !row.IsNull(column)
    let length = ((string)row[column]).Length
    group length by column.ColumnName into g
    select new
    {
        ColumnName = g.Key,
        MaxLength = g.Max()
    };
```

In lambda syntax:

```
var columns = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .SelectMany(row => table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>(), (row, column) => new { row, column })
    .Where(pair => pair.column.DataType == typeof(string) && !pair.row.IsNull(pair.column))
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.column.ColumnName, (key, items) => new 
    { 
        ColumnName = key, 
        MaxLength = items.Max(x => ((string)x.row[x.column]).Length) 
    });
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!  I didn't even know you could do nested LINQ.  Cheers.

Comment: @KKKKKKKK Do note that this will iterate over the whole data table for each column separately, though. This is not a problem if you're only doing this once in a while, but if this is some process you intend to run often (or care about the latency and CPU usage), you might want to avoid this.

Comment: @Luaan: I've added an option to enumerate the rows first.

Answer (score 1):

There's really not much point in using LINQ for this, but going with it:

```
var columnNames = from column in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                  select new { column.ColumnName, column.MaxLength };
```

If you need more information, you can also get the schema itself. This just requires you to `ExecuteReader` some command (`select * from table`) and call `GetSchemaTable` on that data reader. This will result in a table that contains a lot more information about each of theses columns (one row per column).

Comment: Something's not right...  column.MaxLength *always* returns -1.  See: http://i.imgur.com/KhEGgRy.png

Comment: @KKKKKKKK Ah, you mean the longest string in your data, not the size of the column. In that case, a simple `select max(columnname) from table` will be enough.

Comment: Thanks.  Got my answer from Richard.  I know about `MAX(col)`.  But my data lives in a DataTable first, not in Sql yet.